# Variable pointer's member function not drawing to SDL_Surface?

Tags: c++, pointers, set, sdl

I want to use a set to reference some TileObjects (a user defined class) so that I can loop through them and act accordingly, or find a specific one and remove it, etc etc.

The problem is, one thing I want to do is access the member function 'render' which takes an SDL_Surface* and applies an image to it. Outside the set, this works fine. However, using a set of TileObject* as follows

```
for(set<TileObject*>::iterator it = tileObjects.begin(); it != tileObjects.end(); ++it){
    (*it)->render(dest, offset, tileSheet);
}
```

means the image doesn't appear on the screen. I could use a set of TileObjects,

```
for(set<TileObject>::iterator it = tileObjects.begin(); it != tileObjects.end(); it++){
    (*it).render(dest, offset, tileSheet);
}
```

but then I get the "error passing 'const Tileset' as 'this' ...." because some functions I want to access change the values.

What's the correct way to use a pointer's member function to apply a surface in SDL?

I'm using GNU GCC compiler and Code::Blocks if this helps.

Comment: How are you filling the set? Are you sure it actually contains elements?

Comment: I'm filling it earlier on, using tileObjects.insert(). According to tileObjects.size() there's one element in there (though of course, once it works this will change) and the function IS being executed...

Comment: Ok, now I feel like an idiot. The problem was that the render() function used a box2D object, but I'd declared my set as private so the object didn't really exist - meaning it didn't draw the image. Thanks for the input @Mat, sorry for posting a stupid question!

Answer (score 1):

A value inserted into a set cannot be changed in-place because the value acts as a key which is used for all the operations such as insert and search. Due to this (*i) would be a T const, which in your case would be const TileObject. And if the render method is not a const method you, which I suppose is, you would get the error you are seeing.
One option for you could be to change the render method to a 'const method' like

```
void render(dest, offset, sheet) const {...
```

If you are unable to make the method as const, you probably have to check if you are making any mistake in filling up the set in your previous approach. You may have to create a new TileObject and then insert it into the std::set and also remember to delete after done.

Or, another option is to just just use a std::vector instead of std::set.